# What programming language tag to use if you don't really care

Tags: support, tags

The [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) tag wiki suggest that this tag should always be paired with a language tag.
But what if you don't care, like in [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/deep-belief-network-library) where i would be happy with any of 5 languages?
I can't put them all as tags as questions can only have at most 5 tags

Answer (score 4):

Never mind what the tag wiki says. Like the pirates' code, those are "more like guidelines really."

Just as we do for OS agnostic questions, don't tag at all when that's not a significant criteria.

Comment: Also, if it's lahguage (almost) agnostic, explicitly note that in the question.